# Adding Jtable to Tab in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I am developing an java gui. It has TabedPane. I have added panel to tab. How to add jtable to panel which is in tab2;

Comment: have you tried getTabComponentAt(int index)?

Answer (score 1):

To get the compoenent at a particular index use [getComponentAt](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#getComponentAt%28int%29) (as suggested by Jonas Eicher in the comment.)

```
JPanel tabPanel = (JPanel) tabbedPane.getComponentAt(index);
```

Add your table to the panel like the following.

```
tabPanel.add(new JScrollPane(table));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create fields or local variables for your components, so you can reference them, i.e.:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JTable table = new JTable();

tabbedPane.insertTab("title", null, panel, null, 0);
panel.add(table);
```